# How to get LastLogon or LastLogonTimeStamp (whichever is most recent) from all Domain Controllers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So far I have a script for Powershell that shows me Name, SameAccountName, Description, EmployeeID, EmployeeID EmployeeNumber, EmailAddress, LastLogon, Manager, Title, Organization, and if the account is enabled. However, the LastLogon that I am receiving isn't 100% correct since we use many Domain Controllers. The following is my code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,LastLogon,Manager,Title,Department,Organization,Enabled -SearchBase "DC=DELETEDFORANONYMITY,DC=com" |
? {$_. EmployeeID -notlike "EXCLUDE" -and $_.Enabled -notlike "FALSE"}| 
Select Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,@{N='LastLogon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}},Manager,Title,Department,Organization,Enabled |
Export-Csv "C:\scripts\AD_Export.csv"
```

My question is, could anyone help me by adding on to my code so that it includes all Domain Controllers AND outputs the most recent date whether it be LastLogon or LastLogonTimeStamp. I am very new to Powershell so I am still trying to get the hang of it and I can't seem to figure out how to do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-server` parameter to `get-ADUser` to query a specific controller. Once you'll get ahold of a user object on all controllers, collect the `lastLogon` value and select the most recent. This will multiply the latency of your script, so you might probably gain nothing in precision as the users will log on and off after you've collected the data, but still it's a method to query multiple data sources on a single AD entity.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Oops, the `-domainController` is an Exchange Server cmdlets' parameter, the `Get-ADUser` has `-server` for that.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but I don't know enough about Powershell to know exactly how to do what you said.

Comment: `Get-ADDomainController -filter * | % {Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -server $_.name -Properties Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,LastLogon,Manager,Title,Department,Organization,Enabled -SearchBase "DC=DELETEDFORANONYMITY,DC=com" |
? {$_.EmployeeID -notlike "EXCLUDE" }| 
Select Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmployeeID,EmployeeNumber,EmailAddress,@{N='LastLogon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}},Manager,Title,Department,Organization,Enabled |
Export-Csv "C:\scripts\AD_Export_$($_.name).csv"}` An example. Stupid tho.

Comment: This gets all DCs then retrieves all users from each in turn and saves as `AD_Export_(DC name).csv`. Then you should parse the CSV, if you are not able to do this in Powershell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I truly do appreciate it. What I am returning when I use this is: Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Server'. The argument is null or empty. Provide and argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is what I did, check my code and adapt to your needs.

```ps
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$properties = ("Name", "SamAccountName", "mail", "lastLogon", "manager", "company", "createTimeStamp", "department", "logonCount", "pwdLastSet", "userPrincipalName", "physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "employeeID", "accountExpires", "division", "msDS-ResultantPSO")
$users = @{}

foreach ($hostname in (Get-ADDomainController -Filter { IsReadOnly -eq $false } ).HostName) {
    foreach ($user in (Get-ADUser -Server $hostname -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -properties $properties | Select-Object $properties)) {
        if ( $users.Item($user.SamAccountName)) {
            If ( $user.lastLogon -gt $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).lastLogon ) { $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).lastLogon = $user.lastLogon }
            $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).logonCount += $user.logonCount
        }
        else {
            $users.Add( $user.SamAccountName, $user )
        }
    }
}

$hostname = (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -NextClosestSite).HostName
foreach ( $user in $users.Values ) {
    if ( $user.lastLogon ) { $user.lastLogon = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.lastLogon) }
    if ( $user.pwdLastSet ) { $user.pwdLastSet = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.pwdLastSet) }
    if ( $user.accountExpires -eq "9223372036854775807" -or $user.accountExpires -eq "0" ) { $user.accountExpires = "never expires" }
    else {
        $user.accountExpires = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.accountExpires) 
    }
    if ( $user.manager ) { $user.manager = (Get-ADUser $user.manager -Server "$hostname" -properties Name ).Name }
}

$users.Values | Export-Csv -Path C:\ins\users.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```